# Did the Porter Family ever escape from the "Land of the Lost"?

Tags: land-of-the-lost-1991

In 1991 there was a Drama Telecast on ABC named "LAND OF THE LOST".  As per the Wikia Plot:

> The series featured the Porter family—father Tom Porter, son Kevin
>   Porter and daughter Annie Porter—trapped in a parallel universe after
>   their car fell through a time portal while exploring the back country.
>   They soon meet another human, a beautiful "jungle girl" named Christa
>   who came from 1960s San Francisco. Christa became trapped in the Land
>   of the Lost when she was very young and grew up alone.

This TV drama ran for two seasons. So my question is: in the end did the Porter family return to their normal world?  Did they ever escape from "The Land of the Lost"?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  The series was cancelled before an ending was written.  The final episode, aired on December 5th, 1992, did not show the Porter family returning to their world.